ERROR [Profile System Admin] Permission ManageContentProperties depends on permission(s): CustomizeApplication
ERROR
[Profile System Admin] Permission ManageContentProperties depends on permission(s): CustomizeApplication

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the tour and read How to Ask. You will need to edit your question to include more details.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We're not an official part of Salesforce, and >= 99% of people here are customers of Salesforce (and not Salesforce employees). We can't read your mind, see your screen, or log into your org. You need to provide us with enough information to be able to understand what you're trying to do. [Edit] your question to add more information.

To resolve this, you need to edit the affected profiles(Profile System Admin) to give them the "Customize Application" permissions. User capabilities with 'Customize Application' Profile permission.

It's a dependency error, In profile, you can't enable Permission Manage Content Properties due to it's required below 2 Permissions need to be true before that enablement,

Customize Application
View Setup and Configuration

Thanks.
